# Does water that's been left to sit and then reboiled taste different from fresh water boiled once?

Tags: flavor, boiling, coffee, water

*This may sound like a silly question, but I've always wondered:*

If I boil some water and use *some* of it and leave the remainder in the kettle, and then **a few days later** boil that same water again, will it taste the same as if I'd emptied the old water and boiled fresh new water?

I've got a habit of emptying the kettle water and starting with fresh water to boil when I prepare my coffee (using a [French press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_press)), and I'm wondering if there's no good reason to do that.

For what it's worth, the kettle has a top (so I'm ruling out dust as a concern), and the water I'm boiling is tap water that's been through a Brita filter in a jug.

If the taste is different, what's the chemical or physical justification?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is different. Two things happen: the dissolved oxygen boils out, and whatever mineral solids are in there become concentrated as steam evaporates.

Comment: Not that it's necessarily a bad thing.  A little extra minerals in water can significantly affect coffee flavour, but depending on the specific combination, it can be for the better.  There is a town near where I live where coffee made from well water on one side of the river tastes amazing.  Coffee made from well water on the other side is unpalatable.

Comment: The effect of losing dissolved oxygen is also well known in tea-making. Thoroughly boiling the water very quickly extracts the dissolved oxygen. For this reason, enthusiasts of green and oolong tea never bring the water to a full, rolling boil in the kettle. Instead, they wait until the water in the kettle makes a distinctive rumbling sound prior to actually boiling.

Comment: AIUI, gases will re-dissolve in the water after it cools, so it'll end up with the same concentration of dissolved gases that it had originally — having been boiled won't affect that. (However, that doesn't apply to the second point: if the water picks up minerals from the kettle, then it won't lose those over time.)

Answer (score 3):

If it tastes different, it is either evaporating and you're getting a stronger flavor of the same water you drink.

The other thing is that it may be picking up flavor from the kettle.

Answer (score 0):

Dissolved air is eliminated when you boil the water. However this is only really an issue immediately after the water is boiled. Waiting for a long enough time will allow the air to reabsorb into the water.

Comment: And this matters why?